# Why does sam build command display warning "ServerlessRestApi" is a reservered logical ID?

Tags: aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I created the sample app with `sam init`. When I the run `sam build`, I get the warning:
`Your template contains a resource with logical ID "ServerlessRestApi", which is a reserved logical ID in AWS SAM. It could result in unexpected behaviors and is not recommended.`
The template does not have this logical ID. Why does build generate this warning?

### Steps to reproduce

```
❯ sam init  

Which template source would you like to use?  
        1 - AWS Quick Start Templates  
        2 - Custom Template Location  
Choice: 1  

Choose an AWS Quick Start application template  
        1 - Hello World Example  
        2 - Multi-step workflow  
        ...  
Template: 1  

 Use the most popular runtime and package type? (Python and zip) [y/N]:  
 N  

Which runtime would you like to use?  
        1 - dotnet6  
        2 - dotnet5.0  
        ...  
Runtime: 1

What package type would you like to use?  
        1 - Zip  
        2 - Image  
Package type: 1  

Based on your selections, the only dependency manager available is cli-package.  
We will proceed copying the template using cli-package.  

Project name [sam-app]:  

Cloning from https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli-app-templates (process may take a moment)  

    -----------------------  
    Generating application:  
    -----------------------  
    Name: sam-app  
    Runtime: dotnet6  
    ...  
❯ cd .\sam-app  
❯ sam build  
Your template contains a resource with logical ID "ServerlessRestApi", which is a reserved logical ID in AWS SAM. It could result in unexpected behaviors and is not recommended.
Building codeuri: C:\repos\sam-app\src\HelloWorld runtime: dotnet6 metadata: {} architecture: x86_64 functions: ['HelloWorldFunction']
Running DotnetCliPackageBuilder:GlobalToolInstall
```

### Contents of resulting template.yaml

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Sample SAM Template for sam-app

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 10

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src/HelloWorld/
      Handler: HelloWorld::HelloWorld.Function::FunctionHandler
      Runtime: dotnet6
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      MemorySize: 256
      Environment: # More info about Env Vars: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#environment-object
        Variables:
          PARAM1: VALUE
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Comment: @yg-abhi Sure, I have updated my question with the steps I used to create the template and the contents of the template file it generated. The warning I am asking about appears right after the `sam build` command.

Answer (score 9):

Try creating a resource for the API and refer it your handler.

```yaml
Resources:
  MyAPI:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
      Properties:
        StageName: Prod
        Cors:
          AllowMethods: "'GET,POST,OPTIONS'"
          AllowHeaders: "'content-type'"
          AllowOrigin: "'*'"
          AllowCredentials: false



  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src/HelloWorld/
      Handler: HelloWorld::HelloWorld.Function::FunctionHandler
      Runtime: dotnet6
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      MemorySize: 256
      Environment: # More info about Env Vars: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#environment-object
        Variables:
          PARAM1: VALUE
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get
            RestApiId: !Ref MyAPI # **** new property here ****

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${MyAPI}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/" # *** change here {MyAPI}
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Comment: ref: https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#awsserverlessapi

Comment: It does not make sense that the SAM CLI complains about a resource it generates. This is done for convenience and brevity, I don't think someone should have to define the Api if they do not need to.
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-generated-resources-function.html#sam-specification-generated-resources-function-api

Answer (score 1):

"sam local invoke --debug" this command debug your code and share the problem.